# Join two table twice and return duplicate column name

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Suppose I have two table  USER and MESSAGE

```
USER -  id,name
MESSAGES - id,message_from,message_to,message_message
```

So inorder to join I use this co

```
SELECT m.*,u1.*,u2.* FROM MESSAGES m
    INNER JOIN USER as u1
       ON(m.message_from = u1.id)  
    INNER JOIN USER as u2
       ON(m.message_to = u2.id)
```

So now when i print_r out the result in codeigniter it doesn't have the user data for the user message_to.

And I guess even if it return data for both user then it should have some **prefixes to differentiate**

So how should I do that ?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: you have use column alias or case when` to differentiate then.

Comment: use aliases to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to avoid using SELECT * syntax.

I would suggest you specify the columns you want back and give those columns whose names are not unique an alias.

```
SELECT m.id AS MessageId,m.message_from,m.message_to,m.message_message,
    u1.id AS FromId, u1.name AS FromName,
    u2.id AS ToId,u2.name AS ToName FROM MESSAGES m
INNER JOIN USER as u1 ON(m.message_from = u1.id)  
INNER JOIN USER as u2 ON(m.message_to = u2.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use aliases :

```
SELECT m.id,
    u1.id as u1id,
    u1.name as u1name,
    u2.id as u2id,
    u2.name as u2name
FROM MESSAGES m
INNER JOIN USER as u1
    ON(m.message_from = u1.id)  
INNER JOIN USER as u2
    ON(m.message_to = u2.id)
```